# Meaning of "MariaDB works with many clients to migrate Microsoft SQL and Oracle to MariaDB"

Tags: mariadb

https://mariadb.com/blog/getting-microsoft-sql-server-data-mariadb-connect-storage-engine

In the above page, can anyone tell me what this sentence means?

> "MariaDB works with many clients to migrate Microsoft SQL and Oracle to
>   MariaDB"

Does that mean: The company MariaDB works with lots of customers to migrate their SQL Server database or Oracle database to MariaDB?

The thing is I got it as the above meaning but my co-worker translated it to something like "MariaDB itself is compatible with lots of other computers(or components)...". The word "clients" was quite confusing in this sentence. If it is "customers", it must be clearer

Sorry for the strange question, i'm translating the article to Japanese.

Comment: Not really a question appropriate for SO, for several reasons. You may want to erase it before the downvoting starts...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on, maybe, english.stackexchange.com

Comment: I was confused to post it here or in english channel. The thing is it is a technical English question not merely English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it works with lots of clients to migrate from Oracle or MS SQL Server. You can call MariaDB's support to know more about their clients.

[MariaDB Database Migration Team](https://mariadb.com/services/mariadb-mysql-consulting/mariadb-database-migration)

This is pretty common in databases even MySQL has Percona which helps in migrating etc.

Comment: Your "clients" meant customer? and "it" meant the company or the database management system MariaDB?

Comment: Yep, I meant customer!!

Comment: Actually your answer is not really clear so i just wanted to hear other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Sure, MariaDB will sell you its consulting services for the conversion services.  But the statement also means that the "Connect Storage Engine" feature of MariaDB (not MySQL) provides a tool to facilitate the conversion.

MySQL Workbench is another tool for conversion.

Comment: "MariaDB works with many clients to migrate Microsoft SQL and Oracle to MariaDB". Did you mean this statement? The word "clients" can also mean a tool/software like "CONNECT storage engine" or other engines?

Comment: "Client" could mean a company, a person, non-server machine, or a piece of software.  The "for more information" paragraph makes it clearer (to me).

Comment: Yes, I know those meaning of the word client but in the above sentence. What meaning is used was my original question