# As for the expression of MariaDB's manual

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-connect-engine

I learn about MariaDB reading the below page.

https://mariadb.com/blog/getting-microsoft-sql-server-data-mariadb-connect-storage-engine

The part of the first sentence "MariaDB works with many clients" is a little bit vague for me.

Could you tell me what this means if you were a native English speaker or an advanced English leaner?

Here are the options.

(a) The MariaDB foundation cooperates with other companies or organizations.
(b) The MariaDB server works with other middleware such as ODBC.

Comment: Amazing how two very similar questions can come in almost simultaneously - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39296373/meaning-of-mariadb-works-with-many-clients-to-migrate-microsoft-sql-and-oracle

Comment: Thank you for your comment. He is my colleague.We talked about the above question, sorry about that.